# Process was killed -- why? How can I find out?

Tags: terminal, macos, crash

I have written a computer program in C++, compiled it and ran it within terminal using the command line. This program has run fine many times, but it appears that whenever its accumulated CPU time exceeds 60 minutes (which occurs after about 9 minutes as it runs at ~700% on eight threads) it is killed by the run-time system (at least that is suggested by monitoring it using `top`).

There is no error or other message, but merely the word "Killed" printed to the command line:

```
MacBook-Pro-8:~/directory> ./program_name options
Killed
```

Is there a limit on the accumulated CPU time for such processes? How can I find out what killed my process? How can I avoid this?

---

Following the suggestion to run this in a debugger, here is the result:

```
Process 90937 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGKILL
frame #0: 0x000000010001fc50 captureISO`tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<WDutils::Parallel::details::blocked_range_terminating<unsigned long>, (anonymous namespace)::simulations::sampleSome(bool)::$_2, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run_body(WDutils::Parallel::details::blocked_range_terminating<unsigned long>&) [inlined] tbb::concurrent_vector<(anonymous namespace)::simulations::initialCondition, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<(anonymous namespace)::simulations::initialCondition> >::push_back(this=0x00007fff5fbfebd0)::simulations::initialCondition const&) at concurrent_vector.h:846 [opt]
   843      iterator push_back( const_reference item )
   844      {
   845          push_back_helper prolog(*this);
-> 846          new(prolog.internal_push_back_result()) T(item);
   847          return prolog.return_iterator_and_dismiss();
   848      }
   849
```

Thus, the error occurred within `tbb_concurrent_vector.h` in a call to placement `new`, suggesting a lack of memory. Though I'm still mystified why this should result in a kill signal. But this appears off topic here. I have [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125924/tbb-allocation-issuing-a-kill-signal).

Comment: In the code are you catching signals?

Comment: @Mark No, I don't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there’s no limit on accumulated CPU time for processes on macOS.

It seems likely that your program stopped due to issues such as bugs in the program, lack of memory, or similar. In order to find out what happened, try starting your program in the debugger and look at the backtrace.

In addition you should replace the signal handler in the program with one, that prints out which signal it receives. You could potentially also change the program not to kill itself when receiving the signal, but instead do something - like for example freeing up memory. It depends on the signal you’re receiving whether or not it can be ignored.

Comment: *you should replace the signal handler in the program with one, that prints out which signal it receives* -- how can I do that?

Comment: This is definitely not the immediate result of a bug, but perhaps due to lack of memory. However, in that case I'd expect the code to first start swapping. That is not happening, though.

Comment: @Walter You might need to ask that follow on question on a programming site since we’re focused on scripting and how the OS works. The on-topic answer here is the OS doesn’t log signals being sent. Also, [enabling logging might be some work](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) but running it in a debugger might help you catch the termination cause?

Comment: However the question re replace the signal handler in the program  will be too broad for Stack Overflow as you should not just cut and paste code but also need some understanding of what signals are.

Comment: Check out the edit @Mark - it’s getting sigkill and there is code - so this likely won’t get caught as non MCVE on SO. Walter is clearly skilled and getting right to the issue.

Comment: @Walter Try using top to check memory consumption while running the program. Seems like you are allocating a lot, swapping and eventually provoking the OOM killer to stop your program.

Comment: Using tbb makes things more complex but see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/controlling-memory-consumption-with-intel-threading-building-blocks-intel-tbb-scalable @bmike it is nowhere near an MCVE that code is insiode a large third party library. My comment re signals is not so relevant

Answer (score -3):

Here I put the final solution. I tried many, the best method is reinstall brew.

Step1:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Step2:
Install homebrew

```
cd /opt 
mkdir homebrew # if not exist, just create one.
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Then, problem solved.

Comment: Are you sure this answer is for this question?